# Magento 2 Block Payment and Order

Tags: magento2, orders, plugin, exception

I am trying to write a plugin that will block a payment and place order based on a condition.

I have this:

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
              <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
                  <arguments>
                      <argument name="columns">
                          <item name="veratad_action" xsi:type="string">sales_order.veratad_action</item>
                      </argument>
                  </arguments>
              </virtualType>
              <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
                      <plugin name="veratad_ageverification_before_order" type="Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin\Ageverification" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
                </type>
    </config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/Ageverification.php

```
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Plugin;

      use Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement as CheckoutPaymentInformationManagement;

      class Ageverification {

          public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
          CheckoutPaymentInformationManagement $subject,
          $cartId,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
          \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress
          ) {

            $action = "FAIL";

            if($action != "PASS"){

                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(
                  __('Your order has been blocked.')
                );
              }
            }

          }
```

The exception is not firing and the order is being placed. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to put your di under  `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`.